# data synchrnization multiple android devices and single PHP server

Tags: php, android, database

I am trying to implement a PHP server with SQL in back end. 
I have also developed an android APP which records data in sqlite database. The data base has multiple tables with over 500 data (columns). 
When the user hits the sync button in app the "fresh" data should be uploaded and a updated in server and latest copy be downloaded to android device.

I am confused with how to design such an architecture and keep track of changes in such a setting.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a sub-project I've been working now for several days. There are so many concepts and challenges that I don't know where to start. What are you especially confused with? The sync logic? Networking? Authentication? REST/JSON on Android side? Security? Does multiple devices mean devices from same user oder different users (Google Accounts)?

Comment: I am mainly concerned with sync logic. The data is synced on-demand by user when he gets in network range. Security, authentication and networking etc is handled already.  Major issue is how to track changes in tables and columns.

Answer (score 0):

**Querying**

In server Side:

- Create your database with the multiple tables
- Create a web service to fecth your Data , for exemple you do your query and retrun a Json format.

In Android side :

- Use a Http client to read the web service Data.
- Parse the returned Data with json Android class: (jsonArray and JsonObject )
- Put the parsed Data into your Sqlite Data Base which have the Same structure of your Server Data Base ( In preference Same Column Names , Same table name etc...)

**Updating**

In server side :

- Create a web service to update your DataBase

In Android side :

- Use a HttpClient to consume your Web Service using Post type

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt help me. The concepts you mentioned are too broad for my question.

Comment: You can Create this using php file, if you want I cant share with you the source code

Comment: That would be highly appreciated. Thanks. I mostly need the design i am happy tow rite the code.

Answer (score 0):

I will share how synchronize data between Android application and PHP server USING PHP files , it's more easy than web service etc.. and it's give the same result with the same return.

**Querying**

*** -> PHP side :***

- Create your Table Structure for example : MyTableName : columns Login / Password
- Create a PHP file to query data from your table name

  ```
  <?php
  //To Connect to your Data base
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("YourDataBaseName");
  // To execute a query from Your table

    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM `Your_Table_Name");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    $output[]=$row;

   // Convert to Json format 
   print(json_encode($output));
   // mysql_close();
  ?>
  ```
- Name your PHP file as your table Name for example : MyTableName.php
- Put this file in your root server directory : for example in Wamp server the www directory
- Test the return data using a browser, using your URL like 
  [www.localhost/MyTableName.php](http://www.localhost/MyTableName.php), normally you will have all your query
  content in Json format.

*** -> Android side :***

- Download this class 'ClientHTTP' https://www.dropbox.com/s/odpaus1tjhd9orv/ClientHTTP.java
- Add Internet Permission in your manifest.
- Inside the click of your button Synchronize put :

  ```
  String lReturn=_myClientHtpp.readFromUrl(www.localhost/MyTableName.php);
  // It will return a json format (Like navigator)
  //Code to Clear your data from Sqlite data base  TABLE ....

   try {
   // Create your Json Array
   JSONArray lList=new JSONArray(lReturn);
   // Iterate the json arry to get each Json object
   for (int i = 0; i < lList.length(); i++) {

  JSONObject lObject=lList.getJSONObject(i);

  String lLogin=lObject.getString("Login");
  String lPWD=lObject.getString("PassWord");

  //Code to Insert in Sqlite data base .....
  }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

**updating**

*** -> PHP side :***

```
<?php
//Connect to Database
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("YourDataBase");


 $sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO YourTableName (Login,PassWord) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['PARAM_Login']."','".$_REQUEST['PARAM_PWD']."')");

 if($sql==1){
 echo "true";
 }else{
 echo "false";
 }

// mysql_close();
?>
```

- Put this PHP file in your main server directory www, and name it to
  Insert.php
- Test your Insert using browser with this URL [www.localhost/insert.php?PARAM_LOGIN=test&PARAM_PWD=test](http://www.localhost/innsert.php?PARAM_LOGIN=test&PARAM_PWD=test)
- Typically  you will get 'True' and in your server table name a new
  row with test / test will be added.

*** -> Android side :***

- Inside the click of your 'Add' button write :

  ```
      // List of params
  ArrayList<NameValuePair> lListOfParams=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

  // Param login
  BasicNameValuePair PARAM_Login=new BasicNameValuePair("PARAM_Login", "test from Android");
  // Param PWD
  BasicNameValuePair PARAM_PWd=new BasicNameValuePair("PARAM_PWD", "Test from Android");

  // Add params to List
  lListParams.add(PARAM_Login);
  lListParams.add(PARAM_PWd);

  // Execute the post method from your ClientHttp class
  boolean lIsInsert=_myClientHtpp.SendToUrl("www.localhost/insert.php", lListOfParams);

  if(lIsInsert)
      Toast.makeText(this, "Insert Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  else
      Toast.makeText(this, "Insert Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  ```
- If your have your own server replace localhost per your domain name.
- If you are using emulator , replace your localhost domaine name per
  your actual IP address for example the query URL becomes :
    192.168.1.2/MyTableName.php